# Documents not getting populated in view

Tags: lotus-notes, lotus

I have modified a form with a logic to generate a sequence number while saving the document and it populates in a view. For one form its working fine. when i modify 2 more forms with same logic and referred to same view the documents are not getting populated in the view. I have selected the forms correctly in view selection. What could be wrong? kindly help me.

Regards,
Priya

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If your selection formula in the view is really correct, then the next thing to look at is whether the following two things are true:

- the view has the 'Show response documents in a hierarchy' property
- the two forms that are not showing up have the type 'response' or 'response to response'

Notes views with the response hierarchy property enabled will only show responses in a single special column that must be added to the view.  This is how Notes supports 'threaded' style interfaces, with responses indented under their parents (up to 32 levels).  If what you really want is just a flat tabular view display, and if the above two things are true, then you should either consider changing the form types so that they are no longer responses, or just removing the 'show response documents in a hierarchy' property.

Comment: Thank you so much :) its getting populated now.